# I need to add connection details into data source in C# from windows forms

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, windows-forms-designer

```
    String str="server= " + textBox1.Text ";database=" + textBox2.Text ";UID=" 
    + textBox3.Text ";password="+ textBox4.Text ";";
```

I need to enter the connection details in windows forms and add them to this string.

Comment: You should not do this kind of string manipulations. Use [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in new c# feature you can also use

```
$"server={textBox1.Text};database={textBox2.Text};UID={textBox3.Text};password={textBox4.Text};";
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the proper string concatenation. A better solution would be:

```
String.Format("server={0};database={1};UID={2};password={3};", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
```